# Styling issues on searchkit display

Tags: css, shoreditch, searchkit, formbuilder

We are currently running CiviCRM 5.41.2 and using **Shoreditch 1.0.0-beta.9** with **Shoreditch CiviAdmin Companion Drupal theme** as the admin theme. I used a SearchKit List Display and Afform to create a new tab on the a contact page. The idea is that we could use this as a bottom-shelf landing page for some of our users. This display would allow them to view/edit only a few necessary fields (name, address, select custom fields, etc.). The problem we are running into is that the default styling on the List View isn't allowing us to edit the fields. When I click to edit a field, there is no clear box to click in to actually edit the field. Is anyone else having this issue? Would a theme update to 1.0.0-beta.10 solve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shoreditch theme was downloaded from https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch
Admin theme was downloaded from https://github.com/compucorp/shoreditch-companion-d7-theme

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue, except for the grid display (see below). We are currently on version 5.43 and are also using the Shoreditch theme. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwltt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwltt.png)